# .isalpha() con espacios no funciona en Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
equipos = ["Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Manchester United", "Ajax"]

print (equipos[0])
print (equipos[1])
print (equipos[2])
print (equipos[3])

while True:
    equipo = input("\n¿Con que equipo te gustaria jugar? Escribelo aqui: ")

    if equipo.isalpha() :
        if equipo == "Barcelona":
            print ("Buena eleccion!")
            break
        if equipo == "Real Madrid":
            print ("Buena eleccion!")
            break
        if equipo == "Manchester United":
            print ("Buena eleccion!")
            break
        if equipo == "Ajax":
            print ("Buena eleccion!")
            break
        else:
            print("Elije un equipo de la lista, porfavor.")

    else:
        print ("Por favor, utiliza solo letras.")
```

Al usar el `.isalpha()` he notado que si hay un espacio en la palabra, como Real Madrid, no funciona. Con Ajax y Barcelona funciona perfectamente. Cómo se puede solucionar esto?

Comment: hola user, a parte de *aceptar* considera darle upvote por el esfuerzo realizado. Y aunque mi respuesta no sea la seleccionada, te has fijado en la **nota** que te puse?

Comment: Aunque no está relacionado con tu pregunta en si, que ya está resuelta, (si con tu código) considera sustituir los `if` anidados por una estructura `if-elif-else` , es más eficiente que usar solo `if` ya que en este último caso siempre comprueba todas las posibilidades, con `elif` ignora el resto cuando encuentra una que sastiface la condición. En este código no tiene mucha importancia, solo es una recomendación por si te interesa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) solo devuelve `True` si todos los caracteres de la cadena son alfabéticos y hay almenos un caracter, en caso contrario devuelve `False`.

Si la comprobación también tiene que aceptar espacios en blanco, puedes usar algo así:

```
if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in equipo):
```

Esta expresión será `True` para cadenas que contengan espacios y caracteres alfabéticos. No obstante, si necesitas aceptar también caracteres númericos (por ejemplo `Shalke 04`), deberás modificar la expresión para permitirlos:

```
if all(x.isalnum() or x.isspace() for x in equipo):
```

Answer (score 1):

`isAlpha()` devuelve `true` si todos los caracteres son alfabeticos y al menos hay 1 caracter. Te devuelve `false` porque el espacio no es un caracter alfabetico.

Lo **más sencillo** seria sustituir los espacios por `empty` y luego usar `isalpha()`:

```
equipo.replace(" ", "").isalpha()
```

---

Otra manera para detectar que tiene solo letras (y espacios) puedes usar `Regex`:

```
import re
while True:
    equipo = input("\n¿Con que equipo te gustaria jugar? Escribelo aqui: ")

    pattern = re.compile("^[A-Z ]+$")

    if pattern.match(equipo.upper()):
        if equipo == "Barcelona":
            print ("Buena eleccion!")
            break
        if equipo == "Real Madrid":
    . . .
```

La expresion regular `^[A-Z ]+` admite letras y espacios. Puedes añadir Numeros poniendo:

> `^[A-Z0-9 ]+$`

---

**Nota:** En las comprobaciones que haces de  `"equipo == "Barcelona":"` corres el riesgo que pongan "barcelona" y ya no funcionarte. Para eso, pon a ambos un `upper()` o `lower()` tal que:

> ```
> equipo.lower() == "Barcelona".lower():
> ```